# Angular - error TS2769: No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 5, '(next: null | undefined, error: (error: any)

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 I have this code:

Interface

```
export interface IStudent {
  id?: number;
  first_name: string;
  other_name: string;
  last_name: string;
}
```

service

```
getStudentById(id: number): Observable<IStudent[]> {
  return this.http.get<IStudent[]>(this.api.baseURL + 'students/fetchbyid/' + id, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Component:

```
student!: IStudent;
id!: number;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.loadStudentById();
}


loadStudentById() {
  this.studentService.getStudentById(this.id).subscribe(
    (data: IStudent) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.student = data.results.students;
    },
    error => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
    }
  );
}
```

> console.log(this.id) gives 1, which is correct

console.log(data) gives :

```
results
{
    "student": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Lamptey",
        "other_name": "Puel",
        "last_name": "Akwetey",
    }
}
```

I want to display the student detail based on the id.

But I got this error in the component:

> error TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 5, '(next: null | undefined, error: (error: any)

and it (data: IStudent)

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: `data.results.students` or `data.results.student`?

Comment: @naveen - for data.results.students, it underlines results and gives this error:   Property 'results' does not exist on type 'IStudent[]' .     The same thing for    data.results.students?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues would like to raise up:

1. `students` does not exist in your JSON.
2. `student` is **an object**; **not `Student` array**.
3. Attached JSON is not valid, it should be:

```
{
  "results": {
    "student": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Lamptey",
        "other_name": "Puel",
        "last_name": "Akwetey"
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Solution 1

The model based on JSON should be as below:

> response.model.ts

```js
import { IStudent } from './student.model';

export class StudentResponse {
  results: { student: IStudent };
}
```

> student.service.ts

```js
import { StudentResponse } from '../models/response.model';

getStudentById(id: number): Observable<StudentResponse> {
    return this.http.get<StudentResponse>(this.api.baseURL + 'students/fetchbyid/' + id, this.httpOptions);
}
```

> .component.ts

```js
import { StudentResponse } from '../models/response.model';

loadStudentById() {
    this.studentService.getStudentById(this.id).subscribe(
      (data: StudentResponse) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.student = data.results.student;
      },
      error => {
        this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
      }
    );
}
```

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6hqk8w)

---

### Solution 2

`StudentResponse` in Solution 1 can be replaced with models as below. This solution is suggested if you have the default `IResponse<T>` interface.

> response.model.ts

```js
import { IStudent } from './student.model';

export class StudentKeyValuePair {
  [student: string]: IStudent;
}

export class StudentResponse implements IResponse<StudentKeyValuePair> {
  results: StudentKeyValuePair;
}
```

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9dwzhv)